# Deploy perfect swift with heroku

Tags: swift, ubuntu, heroku, vapor, perfect

I have created backend with **perfectswift**. Now I am trying to deploy that with heroku but I am getting some kind of error while pushing. Help me to solve this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be an issue related with stack compatibility. You need to downgrade your stack:

> heroku stack:set heroku-16 -a Your_App_Name

```
Stack Version            Base Technology
----------------------------------------
Cedar-14 (deprecated)     Ubuntu 14.04
Heroku-16                 Ubuntu 16.04
Heroku-18 (default)       Ubuntu 18.04
```

If you got that warning, means you'll need to use Cedar-14:

> heroku stack:set cedar-14 -a Your_App_Name

---

List of Heroku's stacks:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack